# Equivalent of LINQ let clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have the following code in linq:

```
(from emp in db.EMPLOYEES
 from tab in db.CATEGORY.Where(o => o.Id == 19).DefaultIfEmpty()
 on emp.Id = tab.EMP_ID
let url = (!tab.PAGE.StartsWith("/") && !tab.PAGE.StartsWith("#"))
                                            ? tab.PAGE + "(" + emp.EMP_VALUE + ")"
                                            : tab.PAGE.Contains("?")
                                            ? tab.PAGE + "&Id=" + emp.EMP_VALUE + "&fromSSR=" + BooleanStr.True
                                             : tab.PAGE + "?Id=" + emp.EMP_VALUE + "&fromSSR=" + BooleanStr.True
                        select new EmployyeModel
                         {
                             Id = emp.Id,
                             RedirectURL = tab.NOT_CH_APPROVAL == BooleanStr.True ? url + "&userCanApprove=1" : url,
                         }
```

I need to write the above query in sql server and need help concerning the "let url" part.
How do I translate let in sql server and use it in the select?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `The Let keyword allows to create a new variable that is used in further operations`.
Seems like you need some calculated outputs from a select. some `CASE`'s.

Comment: @Mike:  So I can have a case only.  there are no other way round?

Comment: Yes the `let` can be translated into a `CASE` statement or user-defined function. However `not_cfg` is not defined - is that configuration going to be mirrored in SQL?

Comment: @strickt01:  Sry typo error.  I corrected it.

Comment: @tabby your `Linq` has many `CASE` statements with the your  `?:` operators and `.Contains()`, `.StartsWith()` method

Comment: @Mike:  Yes I wanted to know if there is any other way of doing the let part than CASE, cause I will have many cases here.

Comment: @tabby maybe there is some smart way, that i do not know about. However, i would solve this by doing case statements. Then hide it within a `Stored Procedure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnBuildUrl (
    @page       varchar(100),
    @emp_value  varchar(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS  
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @url varchar(1000)

    SELECT @url = CASE WHEN LEFT(@page, 1) = '/' THEN 
        @page + '(' + @emp_value  + ')'
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', @page) > 0 THEN
            @page + '&Id=' + @emp_value  + '&fromSSR=T'
        ELSE @page + '?Id=' + @emp_value + '&fromSSR=T' END
    END

    RETURN @url
END
GO
```

Then call it in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT emp.Id,
    CASE WHEN tab.NOT_CH_APPROVAL = 'T' THEN dbo.fnBuildUrl(tab.PAGE, emp.EMP_VALUE) + '&userCanApprove=1'
    ELSE dbo.fnBuildUrl(tab.PAGE, emp.EMP_VALUE) END AS RedirectURL 

FROM EMPLOYEES emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORY tab
ON tab.EMP_ID = emp.Id
AND tab.Id = 19
```